# How should my Django file structure be set up?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to set up my django file structure. I really don't understand this. It just isn't pointing to where I'd like it to go:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media/')
```

I'm trying to build a file structure like this:

```
mysite
  myapp
  static
    admin
    css
    js
    img
  media
    tmp
  templates
    base.html
  manage.py
```

So I'd like to get the `settings.py` to point to the right direction, I'm just at a loss doing so.

--------- edit ----------

It's not loading any of my content in those files, except for the templates

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/main.css">
        <!-- Remove line below to disable test link -->
        <a href="/test/" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Back To Test Page</a>
        <title>My site - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: #ADADAD; background-image:url('{{STATIC_URL}}img/r.jpg'); background-attachment:fixed;}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/test/">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="/test/">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="/test/">test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </style>
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            {% block footer %}
                &copy; Copyright 2014 by <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Me</a>.
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The picture doesn't get loaded

Comment: How is your web server configured? WSGI? If so, you may need to run the `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` command to collect the static files from each app folder's nested `/app/static/` folder into a single project `/static/` folder.

Comment: I ran that, and it pulled the admin folder into the static folder

Comment: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

0 static files copied, 69 unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your project structure according  to this sample project [Link](https://github.com/yogeshdmca/mywebsite).and you can also use Unipath for set you dynamic path in your setting.py file. you can run this project with collect static or without collect static.